# Image loading time in windows phone apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

i m creating a app in which I need to change the source of the image on button `click.eg` if the images are:

> sample1.png, sample2.png, sample3.png ...

I have written this code on button click:

```
int count=1;
imagename.Source=new BitmapImage(new uri("/sample"+count+".png",uriKind.Relative));
```

but the problem is when I run the app on a device it takes some time to load the image source everytime the button is clicked whereas on the emulator it changes properly.is there any way to reduce the loading time on device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int count=1;
```

BitmapImage bmp=new BitmapImage();

StorageFile sFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\Images\img" + count + ".png");

```
        var fileStream = await sFile.OpenReadAsync();

           await bmp.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
```

Answer (score 3):

> is there any way to reduce the loading time on device?

As far as I know: no. If performance is unsatisfactory, you may want to try with some caching. Basically, instead of creating a new BitmapImage each time, re-use the old ones.

First, pre-load the bitmaps. Don't forget to set the `CreateOptions` property, otherwise the picture won't be loaded until you assign it to an actual Image control:

```
var bitmaps = new List<BitmapImage>(count);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new uri("/sample" + i + ".png",uriKind.Relative));
    bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
    bitmaps.Add(bitmap);
}
```

Then, re-use them as needed:

```
imagename.Source = bitmaps[1];
```

Please be aware that it will increase the memory usage of your app, so don't do that with large pictures. Performance is often a compromise between CPU time and memory usage.

Comment: I believe just creating the BitmapImage will not load the image, it will just be loaded when you set it as a source of the Image..

Comment: That work on windows phone but i don't think it work in winRT (it is the default in winRT and there is no CreateOption to prevent the image to be loaded in background) (created an answer which work on winRT)

Answer (score 1):

Like KooKiz said you can prefetch the image but to force the load of the images, I believe you will need to use SetSourceAsync, here is an example:

```
 StorageFile file= await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("appx-data:////sample" + i + ".png"));
        using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        }
```

Also what could be possible to do is for you to preload a thumbnail version of the image first (by using `file.GetThumbnailAsync` for example) and then the full image latter.

Finally if the images you are loading are actually bigger than the resolution of the surface you are loading it on, another parameter you can set on the Bitmap object is DecodePixelHeight and DecodePixelWidth.

Comment: i tried this in windows 8 store app it is showing this error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Storage.StorageFile>' to 'Windows.Storage.StorageFile'

Comment: @SonaliChalke Small typo, the there were an await missing on the first line, updated my response

Comment: thanks for the answer but it was throwing an exception "Value does not fall within the expected range." so I made some modifications. StorageFile sFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\Images\scene 6\macd\m" + macdcount + ".png");

            var fileStream = await sFile.OpenReadAsync();       this is working.